# How to redirect @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have link with parameter:

```
[http://localhost:8545/Admin/Agent/ManageUser?agentId=3230][1]
```

After change language new link:
[http://localhost:8545/Admin/Agent/ManageUser][2]

have error beacause haven't ?agentId=3230
i use :`<input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@Url.Action(null)" />` 
i don't know edit @Url.Action(null), please help me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this input

```
<input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), new { agentId = Request.QueryString["agentId"] })" />
```

Firs parameter if `Url.Action` is `controller` name, second parameter is `action` name and last one the `routeValues` can you add query strings in URL.

Comment: thanks for help i use  value="@Request.Url.PathAndQuery" it's still Url + PathAndQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to return the user to the same URL he was before changing the language, just keep the full URL in your hidden `input` as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" />
```

Also (assuming your `ChangeLanguage` method is accessibly using the same host-name), you could simply do:

```
public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string lang)
{
    // something like...
    // Session["Lang"] = lang;

    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```